# Drawing feynman diagram with Feynmf

Tags: feynman, feynmf, feynmp

I'm trying to create the diagram below using the feynmf package, but I'm extremely inexpert and I don't know where to start to create the two protons that enter the blob. Im happy for the two blue lines to come out as dashed lines if coloured lines are impossible in feynmf, but I would really appreciate some help with this.

Equally if there are other easy to learn packages that could make this, I'm open to learning something else!

Thanks!

[image: Desired diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the advice from staircase above and after asking another question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568020/change-angles-lengths-and-widths-in-feynmf/568024#568024) the final diagram that I'm happy with can be made using this code:

```
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}  
   \begin{fmfgraph*}(100,40)
    \fmfleft{i2,i3}
       \fmflabel{$p$}{i2}
       \fmflabel{$p$}{i3}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}    
    \fmf{plain}{i2,b,i3}
    \fmf{dashes,label=$h$,label.side=left}{b,c}
  \fmf{plain,foreground=blue,label=$\color{blue}s$,label.side=left,width=3}{o1,c,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmfblob{.1w}{b}
    \fmfdot{c}
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i2,__b) shifted (thick*(-0.75,0.5))}
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i2,__b) shifted (thick*(0.75, -0.5))}  
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i3,__b) shifted (thick*(0.75,0.5))}
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i3,__b) shifted (thick*(-0.75, -0.5))}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

[image: Final result with hatched blob]

Or for a shaded circle instead of the hatched blob, change `\fmfblob` to `\fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=65,decor.size=3mm}{b}`:
[image: Final result with shaded circle]

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you have heard of [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/). You can draw things from their website and get compilable TiKz codes.
In fact, the Feynman diagram is one of the examples they have provided.

Answer (score 2):

This is based on details from [Parallel lines in Feynman Diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121802/parallel-lines-in-feynman-diagram) but I am unable to mark this as a duplicate (sorry no idea how to) so decided I should put it as an answer.

Sadly this isn't the easiest in feynmf but it is possible.

The way to draw it is to produce the diagram with just the central lines for each of the proton legs and then use \fmfi (feynmf immediate mode) to draw shifted copies of the legs.

If the original line is drawn with

```
\fmf{plain}{i1,b}
```

then the two extra lines could be drawn with

```
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i1,__b) shifted (thick*(-0.5,2))}
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i1,__b) shifted (thick*(0.5,-2))}
```

You may need to play with the shifts but make sure that the two shifts are exactly the opposite of each other for it to look good.

Also it is useful to know that the first argument for \fmfi can be any line type that can be used with \fmf so dashed lines, arrows, gluon squiggles or anything that can normally be produced can also be produced for the copies.

Also you also asked for how to do colour. This is possible if you use feynmp and metapost rather than feynmf and metafont. This is the only difference between the two packages. feynmp supports colour as metapost supports colour where as metafont only supports black and white. Once you are using feynmp adding colour is as simple as specifying the forground=blue or some other option in first argument to the fmf command.

```
\fmf{plain,foreground=blue}{i1,b}
```

If you need a colour other than a built in one the syntax is a little awkward as the commas need doubling but is listed in the color section of the manual which is available at https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/feynmf/fmfman.pdf

Comment: I really like this solution but I'm having trouble getting it to work. This works:
`\fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{b}
    \fmf{plain}{i1,b}
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i1,__b) shifted (thick*(-0.5,2))}
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i1,__b) shifted (thick*(0.5,-2))}
    \fmf{plain}{i2,b}
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i2,__b) shifted (thick*(-0.5,2))}
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i2,__b) shifted (thick*(0.5,-2))}
`
But as soon as I change `\fmfright{b}` to `\fmfright{c}` and add `\fmf{dashed}{b,c}` I get no output

Comment: To update: I still can't get this to work. Obviously `fmf{dashed}` was meant to be `\fmf{dashes}` but even `\fmf{plain}` doesn't work.
I really want to use this solution because I can implement it in LaTeXiT and automatically get the diagram with a transparent background as I want. I'd love any help you could give me

Answer (score 2):

A pstricks solution with `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{sansmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-1.5)(2.5,1.5)
\psnode(-1,1.2){up}{$p$} \psnode(-1,-1.2){dp}{$p$}
\pnodes(2.5,0.5){us}(2.5,-0.5){ds}(0,0){O}(1.2,0){I}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed, dash = 5.5pt 4pt, nodesepA=5pt]{O}{I}\naput[labelsep=2pt]{\sansmath $h$}
\pcline[linewidth=4pt, linecolor=blue](I)(us)\naput[labelsep=0pt]{$s$}
\pcline[linewidth=4pt, linecolor=blue](I)(ds)\nbput[labelsep=0pt]{$s$}
\psset{doubleline, doublecolor=Gainsboro, doublesep=4.5pt, nodesepA=10pt}
\pcline(up)(O)\pcline(dp)(O)
\psset{doubleline=false}\pcline(up)(O)\pcline(dp)(O)
\psdot[dotscale=2](I)
\psdot[dotstyle=Bo, dotscale=2.8, fillcolor=Gainsboro](O)%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I compile this? And how can I get rid of the white background and only keep the lines?

Comment: The standard way uses `latex->dvips->pstopdf`. Note that `pdflatex`  cannot make by itself  the computations require by postscript. The direct way ises `xelatex` as compiler. I don't see which white background you mean?

Comment: When I produce the diagram the lines come out on a white background, which means that if I copy it onto a coloured background then it doesn't blend in. I'd like to have only the lines with a transparent background. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I think I see. Actually, there's not background, but the  bounding box of the image takes the place of the background. Perhaps, see whether removind the dimensions of the `pspicture` solves the problem (or replacing this environment with the `postscript` environment). If it doesn't work, could you post a minimal code illustrating this problem?

Comment: Commenting the (-1.5,1.5)(2.5,1.5) retains the white background but shifts the diagram so that the bottom left corner of the page is the centre of the diagram.
Adding `\usepackage{pst-pdf}` and changing `\begin/end{pspicture}` to `\begin/end{postscript}` gives a very strange output, but I can't add pictures here...

Comment: Please post a minimal code that we can play with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115380/discussion-between-beth-long-and-bernard).