# Change angles, lengths and widths in feynmf

Tags: diagrams, feynman, feynmf, latexit

I'm trying to draw the following diagram in feynmf:
[image: Desired image]

I want to do it in feynmf because it's easy to do in LaTeXiT which means that it automatically comes out with a transparent background, and because I'm starting to have some familiarity with the package.

I asked for advice on how to draw it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567751/drawing-feynman-diagram-with-feynmf).

And someone helpfully told me both how to add extra lines to a vertex and how to change the colours of lines.

I now have the following picture, which is obviously approaching the desired result but is not there yet.

[image: Current best]

I would like to have the lines in from i1 and i2, and out to o1 and o2 shorter and tighter, but currently the dashed line doesn't appear at all. I would also love it if I could change the width of the blue output lines to be thick as in the desired outcome.

The code is currently:

```
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}  
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(100,100)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}     
    \fmfright{o1,o2}    
    \fmf{plain,tension=0.05}{i1,b}
    \fmf{plain,tension=0.05}{i2,b}     
    \fmfblob{.17w}{b}
    \fmf{dashes}{b,c}
    \fmf{plain,foreground=blue,tension=0.05}{c,o1}
    \fmf{plain,foreground=blue,tension=0.05}{c,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i1,__b) shifted (thick*(-1.5,1))}
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i1,__b) shifted (thick*(1.5,-1))} 
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i2,__b) shifted (thick*(1.5,1))}
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i2,__b) shifted (thick*(-1.5,-1))} 
    \fmfdot{c}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are giving a too low tension to the external lines, and the internal line contracts to almost nothing. I would define four right vertices, draw a phantom line, then freeze the vertices and only in the end add the two external lines on the right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}  
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(200,100)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
       \fmflabel{$p$}{i1}
       \fmflabel{$p$}{i2}
    \fmfrightn{o}{4}    
    \fmf{plain}{i1,b,i2}
    \fmf{dashes,label=$h$,label.side=left}{b,c}
    \fmf{phantom}{o1,c,o4}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmfblob{.1w}{b}
    \fmfdot{c}
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i1,__b) shifted (thick*(-1.5,1))}
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i1,__b) shifted (thick*(1.5,-1))} 
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i2,__b) shifted (thick*(1.5,1))}
    \fmfi{plain}{vpath (__i2,__b) shifted (thick*(-1.5,-1))} 
    \fmf{plain,foreground=blue,label=$\color{blue}s$,label.side=left}{o2,c,o3}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This plus two phantom lines on the left produced exactly the right geometrical distribution.

Comment: @BethLong Well, the whole point of this construction was to get the angle smaller in the outgoing lines as in the picture you posted in the question. If you wanted both angles to be smaller, the whole phantom stuff with two extra vertices is an overkill. Just specify a smaller y-height for the `fmfgraph`, e.g. `(150,50)`.

Comment: Changing the x, y ratio was exactly what I needed. My very last question is whether I can get the hatched blob to be shaded instead

Comment: @BethLong `\fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=30,decor.size=6mm}{b}` or something similar.